# SQL group by and limit

Tags: mysql, group-by

If I have a query like

```
select sum(number) as points, user from point
where expiryDate < NOW()
group by user
limit 1;
```

will the DB need to process the entire point table even though it will only need to return 1 row (or afew rows).

---

**Some background**:

Users have points that can expire, when points expire, I want to process it. Here I am querying for expired points for each user. Since there are possibly many such points, I am trying to do this process in batches, thus the `LIMIT`. But my guess is this does not actually optimize anything if the DB searches the entire DB anyways. Is there a better way?

Comment: probably, yeah. but remove the "group by user" part, and it shouldn't

Comment: GROUP BY results in an implicit ORDER BY (although deprecated from MySQL 5.6 it would seem). As such it would seem that it will likely process the full result set before applying the limit.